# I need a regular expression to handle multiple date formats

Tags: regex, date-format, date-formatting

I need a regular expression that can handle these date formats:

- 2010-1-1
- 2010-6-01
- 2010-06-1
- 10-10-2010
- 10/10/2010
- 2010/10/10

Is this possible or would I be better off creating multiple regular expressions for each format?

Comment: It probably won't be very restrictive to allow all of those things, or really crazy long/complex.  Might be better the have a few restrictive ones that are easier to deal with then one giant complex one.

Comment: I think you might be able to split this up into 2 or 3 regular expressions.  The first 3 should be easy to combine, as would the 4th and 5th example.

Comment: Do you _really_ need a regex, or are you working with a language that already provides robust date parsing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a pipe (\|) to combine regular expressions, so as long as you can write a regex for each of these, you can paste them all together, e.g. this ought to match the first two dates: "\([12][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[1-9]-[1-9]\|[12][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9]-0[1-9]\)" (You haven't clearly specified the formats, so this probably needs to be generalized for your actual problem.)

However, you've got some bigger questions you might need to consider.

What exactly does 10-11-2010 mean? Is that October 11, or November 10?

Are you assuming only valid dates? What are you going to do about 2010-1-32? What about 2010-2-29?

Answer (score 1):

You'd better to use different format validators with `|`, like:

```
/\b[\d]{4}-[\d]-[\d]\b
|
\b[\d]{4}-[\d]{1,2}-[\d]{1,2}\b
|
\b[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{4}\b
|
\b[\d]{2}\/[\d]{2}\/[\d]{4}\b
|
\b[\d]{4}\/[\d]{2}\/[\d]{2}\b/x
```

but please, note, that *validate* date and *find it occurrence* are not same issues. All your dates are valid dates in terms of [standard strtotime](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html) - so you can use that fact to validate (not search) your dates.

Answer (score 1):

try `\d{2,4}[-/]\d{1,2}[-/]\d{1,4}`  http://regexr.com?36goq - see in action

Comment: This will match, for example, `00/0-0` .